# for_each( for_each() )?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, foreach

This works, for_each passes vectors

```
std::vector<int> v(10, 1);
std::vector< std::vector<int> > vv(10, v);
auto vvit = vv.begin();

std::for_each(vvit, vv.end(), f);
```

to function f which applies for_each anew to work with inner vector ints

```
void f(const std::vector<int>& v) {std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), def);}
```

but for_each within for_each

```
std::for_each(vvit, vv.end(), std::for_each((*vvit).begin(), (*vvit).end(), def));
```

and function for just ints

```
void def(const int& i) { std::cout << i; }
```

does not. (Nor with bind, if I tried correctly.) The compiler says that the def function cannot apply the right conversion i.e. from vector allocator (the vector's position pointer?) to const int&, something the former example achieves with the vector-separating function f.

Is this complicated or trivial?

Comment: What is your question?  Are you wondering why that doesn't work?  Why would you expect it to?

Comment: sorry, yes, why does for_each not accept an inner for_each as a function argument, the outer applied to the outer vector and the inner one to [each] inner vector? So it is trivial, why?

Comment: on reflection, it should be 'why is the def function not applied in a way that its parameter matches the vector's ints'?

Comment: `for_each` accepts a function that takes an element as its 3rd argument.  `for_each(b,e,f)` is an expression of type `void`.  Thus it is not a valid argument as the 3rd parameter of `for_each`.

Comment: i see, think i needed to hear that. i'll accept as an answer - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution is to pass `for_each` in a lambda:

```
std::for_each(vvit, vv.end(), [f](std::vector<int> const& v)
  { std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), f); } );
```

But what's wrong with

```
for (auto const& v : vv) {
  for (int i : v) {
    f(i);
  }
}
```